# "My response to be aligned with yours"

Tags: phrases

Let's say me and a colleague are going to a meeting and I want to make sure his responses to the questions raised are similar to mine, that we are in agreement and we will responde in a similar manner.

Can I say: "Let's make sure our responses are aligned" or, "Please let me know your views cause I want my responses to be aligned with yours."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While *aligned* may be acceptable, I think a more common word would be *consistent*. People also refer to being *in sync* or *on the same page*.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to say that, and those two ways are certainly acceptable.